# Displaying Error Messages with Thymeleaf in Spring boot is not working

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

[I am using spring boot and thymeleaf for a web application.
I want to catch the error message before an exception is thrown and displayed on the registration form, but it keep giving me a 500 server Error with the custom validation message instead of displaying them in the form

Controller

```java
    import javax.validation.Valid;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    
    import bitsTracker.entity.BitUserRegistrationDto;
    import bitsTracker.service.interfaces.BitUserService;
    
    @Controller
    public class RegistrationController {
    
        @Autowired
        private BitUserService bitUserService;
    
        @GetMapping("/registration")
        public String viewRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("bitUser")  BitUserRegistrationDto bitUserRD) {
            return "registration-form";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/saveBitUser")
        public String registerNewBitUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("bitUser") BitUserRegistrationDto bitUserRD,BindingResult result,Model model) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "registration-form";
            } else {
                bitUserService.saveBitUser(bitUserRD);
                return "redirect:/registration?success";
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Entity DAO

```java
    package bitsTracker.entity;
    
    import lombok.Data;
    
    @Data
    public class BitUserRegistrationDto {
        
        private String userName;
        private String password;
        private String name;
        private String email;
    
        
    }
```

Entity

```java
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "userName"))
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class BitUser {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        
        private String name;
    
        @NotEmpty
        @NotNull
        @Size(min=2, message ="BitUser is too short ")
        private String userName;
        
        @Email
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        private String email;
    
        @NotEmpty
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 8 , message ="Your password should be a minimum of 8 characters and contain at least one number and special character. ")
        private String password;
    
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", //
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), //
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private Collection<Role> roles;
    
        public BitUser(String userName, String name, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
            super();
            this.userName = userName;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.roles = roles;
        }
    
    }
```

HTML File

```html
                    <h1>Registration</h1>
    
                    <form th:action="@{/saveBitUser}" method="post" th:object="${bitUser}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="name"> Full Name </label>
                            <input id="name" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"
                                required autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{name}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="userName"> Bit User Name </label>
                            <input id="userName" class="form-control" th:field="*{userName}"
                                required autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{userName}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label> <input
                                id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required
                                autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{email}" />
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label> <input
                                id="password" class="form-control" type="password"
                                th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{password}" />
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                            <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login
                                    here</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hello, Anas, welcome to the site. Please include your code as text and not in images. Check [ask]

Comment: i found the bug, the validation was on the wrong class, it should be on Entity Dto  not on the Entity class